# What are other use cases of the Repository class in MVVM?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, repository, dagger-hilt

I know its used for getting Data from the server and cache but what else is the repository class used for?
I’m using the MVVM pattern and wonder where to put I/O operations like saving and writing a file.
I also have a coin system in my app and I need to access that coin Int from every screen in my app (settings, profile, home etc), is the Repository a good place to put it?

P.s I'm using Dagger Hilt